# Change Region on GCP App Engine Flex

Tags: region, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a app engine flex project but I am always getting the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Flexible Environment deployments are not supported in the apps region 'europe-west'.

I do know that app engine flex is not supported in Europe at this point in time, but the weird thing is that I do not have an option to select another one, neither at the cli or UI level.

Plus, in my gcloud local config I have region 'us-east1-b' selected as my default region (not sure if this makes any difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 'gcloud init' in your GDK: the account, project and zone in which you are working will be listed. Choose the options you want and everything should be fine. Cheers.